# How to run a Perl (or any CGI script) with a Wordpress installation

Tags: wordpress, perl, cgi

I have a simple wordpress website. I would like to run some perl programs from the cgi-bin folder. But the wordpress install gives a page not found when I put the link into my browser.

I put a simple "hello world" program in the cgi-bin folder, changed the permissions, then tried to execute it with a link.

It seems that wordpress is overriding any links to the cgi folder and presenting a wordpress 404 page. I have no problem running cgi programs on any other website on the same server.

Comment: Sounds like Wordpress isn't important here. Step 1: Get CGI programs working on your server. Step 2: Use the working CGI URLs from Wordpress. Do your CGI URLs work outside of Wordpress? Please tell us (a lot!) more about what you have tried.

Comment: I have 30 websites on this server, they all use cgi without a problem. This is the only word press site. It is a wordpress error page I get.

Comment: Unless you update your question to include a lot more information about a) what you are trying to achieve b) what you have done and c) what problems you are having, I expect this question will be closed within a couple of hours.

Comment: a) I am trying to run a perl program.
b) I put the "hello world" perl program in the cgi folder and changed the permissions. Then I tried to run it with a link. 
c) I am getting a wordpress error page saying the page cannot be found.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, as suggested by the scarcity of responses, this is not a wordpress issue. In fact the cgi-bin folder had the wrong permissions, which triggered the wordpress page not found response.

Comment: I also have the same issue. I'm trying to figure out.